# Simplify lambda return value from spreading

Tags: javascript, typescript

If you've got something like this:

```
const someObjectArray = [
  {property: 'foo', property2: 'bar', property3: 'baz'},
  {property: 'fooDiff', property2: 'barDiff', property3: 'bazDiff'}
]

const someOtherObjectArray = someObjectArray
  .map(({property2, property3}) => ({property2, property3}))
```

Is there a kind of short-form-syntax to express this?

```
map(({property2, property3}) => ({property2, property3}))
```

EDIT:

To make things clearer - since you are duplicating this part `{property2, property3}`, I thought there might be a syntax trick to write it like `.map(({property2, property3}))` or I don't know and you're good.

Comment: what do u really want to simplify? Can u give an example?

Comment: That is the 'short-form-syntax'

Comment: I suppose if the number of properties you're excluding are fewer than those you're including you could use a ...rest. `const someOtherObjectArray = someObjectArray.map(({ property, ...o }) => ({ ...o }));` But is it shorter? and more importantly is it as clear what's happening. Clarity over brevity always.